# Best English grammar book

Tags: grammar

First of all sorry for not asking a technical question.

Actually I need to know the best English grammar book in terms of completeness and depth of every topic.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are at least two different kinds of book you might be looking for: (a) a textbook for learning English (I know of many good ones, but no best ones, since everybody learns differently) or (b) a technical grammar of English ([McCawley 1998](http://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/S/bo3613599.html) is the best one I know. It's not a simple rule book, but rather a textbook for a full-year college course in English syntax, roughly the same size as a calculus text, and requiring about the same level of attention and practice. That said, it has everything.)

Comment: Please note that requests for references are specifically off-topic, and that asking for the "best" reference is often a matter of opinion, which would also make it off-topic. There is a list of [good reference works](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573) on Meta.

Comment: There is an interesting & short & well organized grammar book called `<Grammar for English Language Teachers>`, it's very good & easy to read.